# "nothing to commit, working directory clean" - gray folder

Tags: github, commit, tortoisegit

I have private github repository with folders : lab1, lab2, lab3 etc.
I pulled it and added inside lab1 java project called "ArabskieNaRzymskie".
Inside this project there are some files and there are not seen by TortoiseGit! 
How can I commit all of there files? (It is not .gitignore problem)

GitHub GRAY folder(not clickable)

[image: img]

inside "ArabskieNaRzymskie" folder (no any icon from TortoiseGit)

[image: img2]

Comment: If you tell Tortoise to commit the ArabskieNaRzymskie folder, what happens?

Comment: " No files were changed or added since the last commit"

Comment: It is pretty weird but when I used gitGui and "prune" it worked finally :)

Answer (score 1):

On GitHub, your "ArabskieNaRzymskie" folder should be a **Submodule** if the folder icon is [image] (not [image]), which means ArabskieNaRzymskie is also a repository. Try to show the hiding folder and file on Windows, you will see a **.git file** or **.git folder**.

Since it's a repository, you need to commit your changes/files **inner** that repository.

(In your super repository, you only see "ArabskieNaRzymskie" as a submodule or embedded repository with a "folder" icon. Thay's why you can't see those files inner ArabskieNaRzymskie folder.)

Comment: If you don’t see a .git entry, you need to initialie/update the submodule first.